# Update data in a column that I do not know in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

The update statement is like this

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value, column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value
```

However 
for a simple table

```
cola colb colc cold cole
```

I would like not to update colc and cole

but i do not know the exact structue (I can not tell how many col there, may be colf exist too)

So how to update the column that exclude colc and cole? Thank you

Comment: How do you know which one to include/exclude if you do not know how many columns exist? Or do you have a list of columns `colc` `cole` and need to update the rest not in the list?

Comment: Could you please elaborate? Even if you don't know the structure of the table you have to know the column's names, meaning the number of columns shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I know which one i need to exclude

Comment: if you have data to update, you are apparently know which fields it goes to. your question makes no sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to define all columns of a table when you do a UPDATE statement in MySQL. Only the columns that you tell it to update will be updated.

```
UPDATE your_table
SET
  cola='New Value'
  ,colb='Another'
  ,cold='And Another'
WHERE id_column = 1234
```

This will not change the value of `colc` or `cole`.